# PHP CodeSniffer custom ruleset for multiline function declaration

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I was trying to configure phpcs to use two spaces indentation everywhere instead of 4 but i am stuck at one place, i cannot override rule for multiline function declartion

my code is

```
if (!function_exists('errorlog')) {
  function errorlog(
    Exception $e,
    array $data = []
  ) {
}
```

although this code is giving me error that

**Multi-line function declaration not indented correctly; expected 6 spaces but found 4**

**My Custom Ruleset**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ruleset name="Amit">
  <description>My Custom on top of PSR2</description>

  <rule ref="PSR2">
    <exclude name="PSR2.Classes.ClassDeclaration"/>
    <exclude name="PSR2.ControlStructures.SwitchDeclaration"/>
   <exclude name="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature"/>
 </rule>

 <rule ref="Generic.Arrays.ArrayIndent">
   <properties>
     <property name="indent" value="2"/>
   </properties>
 </rule>

<rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
  </properties>
</rule>

<rule ref="PSR2.Classes.ClassDeclaration">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
  </properties>
</rule>

<rule ref="PSR2.ControlStructures.SwitchDeclaration">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
  </properties>
</rule>

<rule ref="PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
    <property name="requiredSpacesAfterOpen" value="1"/>
    <property name="requiredSpacesBeforeClose" value="1"/>
  </properties>
</rule>


<rule ref="PEAR.ControlStructures.MultiLineCondition">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
  </properties>
</rule>


<rule ref="PEAR.Formatting.MultiLineAssignment">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
  </properties>
</rule>

<rule ref="PEAR.Functions.FunctionDeclaration">
  <properties>
    <property name="indent" value="2"/>
  </properties>
</rule>
</ruleset>
```

Comment: hastebin is BLOCKED in many places. Please update your question.

Comment: You should paste it in your question.

Comment: @delboy1978uk thanks, Ruleset  added in question

Comment: hmm, it seems ok... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the code you had above and ran it against the ruleset provided, with the `-s` flag to show the Sniff reporting the error.

```
<?php
// test.php

if (!function_exists('errorlog')) {
  function errorlog(
    Exception $e,
    array $data = []
  ) {
  }
}
```

`$ ~/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=./rules.xml -s test.php`

Here was my output:

```
FILE: test.php
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 2 ERRORS AFFECTING 2 LINES
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5 | ERROR | [x] Multi-line function declaration not indented correctly; expected 6 spaces but found 4 (Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.Indent)
 6 | ERROR | [x] Multi-line function declaration not indented correctly; expected 6 spaces but found 4 (Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.Indent)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 2 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 90ms; Memory: 6Mb
```

`Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.Indent` is the sniff in question. Gotta find a way to exclude that one!

Comment: Thanks a lot Cameron just add a new rule ref for multiline function declaration and problem solved